# Resetting variable in loop

Tags: java, loops

I have a client class where the value "number" should always be changing accordingly to be the user input but after each loop it stays the same as the first entry, ex: user input F next loop it will print F not anything but. I tried creating a new instance of it with the private method but I kept getting an enum error I didn't know how to approach.

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    boolean test = true;
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6115);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
    PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    //String number;
    while (test) {
        String number;
        number = "";
        System.out.println("Enter any string");
        number = sc.nextLine();
        p.println(number);

        //flushing printstream not variable?
        number = sc1.nextLine();
        System.out.println("CALLED");
        System.out.println(number);
        p.flush();
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter another string? Y/N: ");
        String cont1 = sc.nextLine();
        if (cont1.equals("N")) {
            test = false;
            System.out.println("Goodbye! ");
        }
    }
    s.close();
    sc.close();
    sc1.close();
}
}
private void resetVariable() {
    Client = new Client();

}
```

The error is "Error:(43, 17) java: class, interface, or enum expected" which is puts the cursor right after void in the private object

then "Error:(46, 9) java: class, interface, or enum expected" highlighting the brackets in the private object

Comment: Please show the actual error you get.

Comment: @AndyTurner updated

Comment: You've closed too many `}`s after the `main` method.

Comment: The compiler error you describe has nothing to do with whether `number` acquires only one value and no new values. In fact, it won't acquire any values until the compiler errors are fixed.

Comment: Why do you have `number = sc1.nextLine();` in two different places?

Comment: resetVariable is outside the class (so the compiler is expecting it to be a type of class, not function). Also Client isn't a variable anywhere, so you can't make an assignment to that. Also, resetVariable isn't called anywhere, so just remove the function and it should compile again.

Comment: Please first remove syntax errors from your code.

Comment: Also, what is the point of `s`, `p`, and `sc1`? They aren't really used so you should purge them from the program.

Comment: @Tezra getting it to run with out compile issues isn't a problem I've been doing that originally I just tried adding a reset object to reset it and since that wasn't working it stopped it from compiling not fixing my problem, removing it takes me back to square one, the problem is clearing a value that wasn't changing

Comment: @oso9817 comment out all lines using/referencing s,p,and sc1. I think somehow your socket is contaminating the input, and you don't appear to be doing anything with them. (I think the in/out stream might be shared on the socket some reason?)

Comment: The server its connecting to is crucial its where the input is being manipulated, here's a link to the server https://pastebin.com/y2h48mGp but yes I agree I thought it was the server at first but after debugging and seeing the value in the client wasn't changing I had second thoughts @Tezra

Answer (score 1):

Move your method inside the Class:-

```
    } // This closes main
    //} // This was closing the Class Client
    private void resetVariable() {
        Client = new Client();

    } // This closes resetVariable
  } // This should now close Class Client
```

**Update**: From comments below - You should also think about *instantiating* the class `Client`from the member function `resetVariable`

Comment: Now it says Error:(43, 17) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable client
  location: class com.alonzo.client.Client, in     Client = new Client();

Comment: Why are you instantiating the class form within a method of the class?